# Summing columns in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have an sql server table as follows:

```
c1  c2  c3
X   30.00   0.00
X   15.00   0.00
Y   0.00    20.00
```

Can you please help me obtain:

```
c1  c2       c3      c4 
Z   45.00   20.00   65
```

What I tried so far:

```
select 'Z' AS C1, SUM(c2) as c2, SUM(c3) AS C3, SUM(c3) + SUM(c2) AS c4 
  from Table1
  group by c1
```

gives me this result:

```
C1  c2      C3       c4
Z   45.00   0.00    45.00
Z   0.00    20.00   20.00
```

whereas I want all the sums on one single line.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 'Z' AS c1, SUM(c2) AS c2, SUM(c3) AS c3, SUM(c3) + SUM(c2) AS c4   
  FROM Table1
```

Output:

```
c1 c2 c3 c4             
Z  45 20 65
```